# Select a record from the combobox

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, c#-3.0

I have a ComboBox in my application . I want to select any index other than what is already selected .

```
 int index = ComboBox0.SelectedIndex;
 int count = ComboBox0.Items.Count;

ComboBox0.SelectedIndex = ?
```

How to achieve this without hard coding ?

Answer (score 2):

You could do something like:

```
ComboBox0.SelectedIndex = (ComboBox0.SelectedIndex + 1) % ComboBox0.Count;
```

That will select the next item available in the list.

Comment: I like this approach, but... Say `Count = 6`, and the last item is selected (`SelectedIndex = 5`). Won't this formula return `1`, i.e. it will select the second list item, not the first? Aren't ComboBoxes zero-indexed (at least in C#)?

Comment: @djacobson You're absolutely right. I'll try to think of a way around that (though it may not be a _big_ deal if we're losing just the first entry). Ahhh...fixed it. I just removed the count decrement. I'm always so worried about one-offs that I automatically reduce a count by 1, which isn't necessary here.

Comment: Not sure this logic will always work.  If you are currently on the first item of a 2-item list, SelectedIndex is 0 and Count is 2.  1 % 1 = 0, which is your original selectedindex.  But I could be rusty on this...

Comment: @nycdan My edit fixes that as well. Now, if 0 is selected, 1 gets chosen; if 1, then 0.

Comment: yeah, i like it - very code efficient.  It also won't break if the list only has one item.

Comment: I had a feeling that's what the problem was... Well adjusted, and upvoted. :)

Answer (score 0):

In case you want to select it randomly, you can use something like this:

```
int n = (int)(random * (count - 1));
if (n < index) {
   ComboBox0.SelectedIndex = n;
} else {
   ComboBox0.SelectedIndex = n + 1;
}
```

where random would be variable with:

```
random = new Random();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just need any item other than the current one (and you are sure there are two), this will work as well as any (choose first item if not currently selected, or second item if first is selected):

```
if (ComboBox0.SelectedIndex == 0) ComboBox0.SelectedIndex = 1;
else ComboBox0.SelectedIndex = 0;
```